# Internal Server Error Codeigniter HMVC

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i've migrated codeigniter project to server from localhost but facing issue "**Internal Server Error** (500)". (i've Compressed whole project directory and extracted on server)
What i've tried to fix this.

- Placed index.html file in project root and it is **working** fine
- placed default .htaccess file, also tried without this.
- I tried to echo/print something into index.php file but it is not executing and throws the error "Internal Server Error"
- i've tried to find error_log, and it is empty.
- i've changed the `$config['log_threshold'] = 4;` and tried to find error_log file in `application/log/` but it is empty.
- i've checked the mod_rewrite issue on server and it is also fine and many other projects are executing with no issue.

i am wondering why it comes to index.html but doesn't comes into index.php? What other ways to find and resolve this issue?

Comment: If you add die('TEST'); on top of index.php what's the result?

Comment: It does'nt execute.

Comment: If you have cPanel, go check the PHP version and settings. Probably the error is there. Also, the Internal Server Error is status 500?

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.16 and yes its 500

Comment: Please check your apache error logs, the information will be there.

Comment: change `log_threshold` to `4` in config.php file and then check log in `application/logs` directory for error log.

Comment: @RejoanulAlam I've changed this log_threshold to 4 and tried to find the log file, but the log directory is empty.

Comment: @Esar-ul-haqQasmi now change like `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in `index.php` file where `case` is `production`. hope it will left some clues

Comment: check writable permission to folder application/logs

Comment: @RejoanulAlam I've tried to put `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` but it never comes into index.php file, even i've put `exit();` after that, but still 500.
@hrishi the permissions are 755

Comment: May be something wrong in .htaccess

Comment: @hrishi here is my .htacess, working perfect on localhost. `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] `

Comment: check with adding RewriteBase in htaccess

Comment: Try an empty PHP file with nothing but phpinfo() and see if that executes. If not, it's not the CI install. Also, check the actual server error logs, not the application/logs folder. If CI isn't executing, it won't write to that directory regardless of what you have the log level set to.

Comment: @Joe Yes the info.php into the project root directory executed by approaching its path.

Comment: @Esar-ul-haqQasmi The raw server logs are your best bet, then. I find that, in most of these cases, reinstalling a clean copy of CI is the quickest fix.

Comment: @Esar-ul-haqQasmi please try to change in .htacess at last line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] `

Comment: Does ANY PHP file execute? Might be a server issue even running PHP. Or else there could be a problem running RewriteModule at all. Check the apache-log!

Answer (score 0):

I guess am late but i think you need to add a .htaccess in your root or public folder, that is, where the index.php is, and can contain these:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```